# Como passar argumentos para a execução de um aplicativo android?

Tags: android, parâmetros

Gostaria de saber como passar argumentos para a execução de um app android, ou mesmo criar um arquivo de configuração para ser consultado quando iniciar o aplicativo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isto com [Shared*Preferences*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Com isto, será possível criar uma tela de preferências ou configurações para seu aplicativo. Você vai poder carregar a preferência em qualquer ponto de execução do aplicativo.

## Introdução

---

Shared*Preferences*,  lhe permite a persistência de dados na `key-value`, isto é, para cada chave ou identificador(*string*) você vai ter que associar um valor à esta (*boolean, float, whatever, ...*).

## Em quais casos usar?

---

O **shared*Preferences*** é muito utilizado para guardar informações de configurações do aplicativo. Mas não é recomendado que você guarda informações do usuário (e.g: *sistema de perfil, etc...*)

## Como usar?

---

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences sPreferences = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle cicle) {
        super.onCreate(cicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout); // Coloque seu Layout aqui!

        /**
        * @SharedPreferences
        * @Desc: Quando a activity for criada, o código abaixo vai 'pegar' a preferência "preferences_app_button_red"
        *  Para quando a activity resumir, ele verificar seu valor.
        */
        sPreferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences_app_button_red", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume () {
        super.onResume();

        /** 
         * @Desc: este código verifica se o valor da chave "preferences_app_button_red" é verdadeiro ou falso.
         * @True: Vai mostrar uma toast dizendo que o botão vai ser vermelho...
         * @False: O botão não tem uma configuração de cor vermelha.
         */
        if (sPreferences.getBoolean("preferences_app_button_red", true)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "É vermelho", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Não é vermelho... :/", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Para inserir um valor em uma chave da shared*Preferences*, use:

```
sPreferences.edit().putBoolean("preferences_app_button_red", false).apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

Para passar dados de uma *Activity* para outra, você pode anexar ao *Intent* um objeto *bundle*, que conterá os dados que você enviará. Então a nova activity terá de extrair os dados do *bundle*.

## Enviando bundle

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString(/*id*/,/*dado*/); //Meramente exemplo
intent.putExtra("Bundle", b);
startActivity(intent);
```

## Recebendo e extraindo dados do bundle

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getBundle();
String dado = b.getString(/*id*/);
```

**EDIT**

Para iniciar a *activity* inicial com parâmetros, você vai ter de iniciar a *activity* sem parâmetros primeiro. Colocar os parâmetros em um Bundle, e então lançar a *activity*  inicial com os parâmetros.

Para dividir a inicialização, você pode criar um campo de controle no *bundle* e verificar a existência do campo. Se ele existe, você pode prosseguir com a inicialização, caso contrário, fazer o processo de passagem de parâmetros.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer esta configuração em sua `Application`. A `Application` é a primeira coisa que executa, antes de qualquer `Activity`.

Dentro de sua `Application` você pode, por exemplo, carregar/persistir informações do seu `SharedPreferences`:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        SharedPreferences reader = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String algumaString = reader.getString("algumaKey", "");
        ...

    }
}
```

Não esqueça de adicionar sua `Application` no seu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...
```